# How to join two belongsToMany objects

Tags: laravel, join

I am trying to represent friendships in my Laravel project database.
I have created a table `profile` which contains all user-data.
A second table `profile_profile` with the columns `profile_id` and `friend_id`.

With that I am able to get persons wo wants to be friend with me:

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Profile', 'profile_profile', 'friend_id', 'friend_id');
```

an friends I am want to be befriendet:

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Profile', 'profile_profile', 'profile_id', 'friend_id');
```

But in the end you are only friends if both want that so. So I tried to combined them but join or something similar didn't work.

I did a research on this platform and google over 2 hours. I am afraid that my skills are to limited, but I really like to ask for help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: add another column in the profile_profile table, say, "accepted" as boolean and default to FALSE.

When a user accepts a friend's request, toggle the "accepted" field to TRUE.

Then you could search like `$profile->profiles()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get()`